# page automatically scrolls to cfgrid

Tags: coldfusion, cfgrid

I have a page that is tall enough that it scrolls vertically.  When it finishes loading, the browser automatically scrolls to the bottom of the page where a cfgrid element lives.  It happens in IE, Chrome and Firefox.

I've narrowed the cause down to the JavaScript that the ColdFusion 11 server adds to the top of the page.  If I disable scripts in the browser, the page doesn't automatically scroll to the bottom.

Adding window.scrollTo(0,0) to the body onload doesn't work.  Whatever JS is scrolling to the bottom happens after the onload event.  I haven't tried jQuery's .ready() yet; hoping there is a fix.

Has anyone else seen this and know of a fix or workaround?

Thanks

Here's my code

```
<cfoutput>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    0<br>
    1<br>
    2<br>
    2<br>
    3<br>
    3<br>
    4<br>
    5<br>
    5<br>
    6<br>
    7<br>
    8<br>
    9<br>
    <!-- Lines deleted that push the cfgrid below the bottom of the screen -->
    <cfquery datasource="#application.datasource#" name="testquery">
    select MNU_MENU_ID, MNU_MENU from #application.db_owner#.menu
    </cfquery>
    <cfform name="assays">

       <cfgrid name = "FirstGrid"  title="test" format="html" height="310" width="500"
            stripeRows="true" preservepageonsort="true"
            query = "testquery">

            <cfgridcolumn name="MNU_MENU_ID"  header="ID" width="25" />
            <cfgridcolumn name="MNU_MENU" header="Menu" width="200"  />

            <!--- Hidden Columns --->

        </cfgrid>


    </cfform>

    <script>
        setTimeout(function(){ window.scrollTo(0,0); }, 4000);
        //alert('scroll attempted');
    </script>

</body>
</html>
</cfoutput>
```

Here's the code the browser sees:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */_cf_loadingtexthtml="<img alt=' ' src='/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/resources/cf/images/loading.gif'/>";
_cf_contextpath="";
_cf_ajaxscriptsrc="/CFIDE/scripts/ajax";
_cf_jsonprefix='//';
_cf_websocket_port=8577;
_cf_flash_policy_port=1243;
/* ]]> */</script><script type="text/javascript" src="/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/yui/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/yui/animation/animation-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/ext/ext-all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/ext/source/widgets/DataView.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/ext/source/widgets/SplitButton.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/messages/cfmessage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/package/cfajax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/package/cfgrid.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/resources/ext/css/ext-all.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/resources/cf/cf.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CFIDE/scripts/cfform.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/CFIDE/scripts/masks.js"></script>

<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test</title>

<script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */
    ColdFusion.Ajax.importTag('CFGRID');
/* ]]> */</script>

<script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */
    ColdFusion.objectCache['FirstGrid'] = new ColdFusion.Grid.Actions('cfgrid148239339981943');
    _cf_GRIDTAG_initAjaxGrid_148239339981944=function()
    {
        var _cf_gridColModel = [{header:'ID','colName':'MNU_MENU_ID',id:'FirstGrid_MNU_MENU_ID','name':'MNU_MENU_ID',dataIndex:'MNU_MENU_ID',menuDisabled:false,sortType:'asFloat',sortable:true,flex:1,width:25},{header:'Menu','colName':'MNU_MENU',id:'FirstGrid_MNU_MENU','name':'MNU_MENU',dataIndex:'MNU_MENU',menuDisabled:false,sortType:'asUCString',sortable:true,width:200},{header:'CFGRIDROWINDEX','colName':'CFGRIDROWINDEX',id:'FirstGrid_CFGRIDROWINDEX','name':'CFGRIDROWINDEX',dataIndex:'CFGRIDROWINDEX',menuDisabled:false,sortType:'asFloat',sortable:true,hidden:true}];
        var _cf_gridData = [[1,'Home',1],[2,'Compounds',2],[3,'Dashboard',3],[4,'Authorize',4],[5,'Reports',5],[6,'Administration',6],[7,'Help',7],[8,'Dataload',8],[9,'Logout',9],[17,'cmpIdentification',10],[18,'cmpAcquisition',11],[19,'cmpRegistration',12],[20,'cmpReview',13],[21,'cmpChemistry',14],[23,'stdInVitro',15],[10,'adminAssays',16],[11,'adminStudies',17],[12,'adminSubmitters',18],[13,'adminLabs',19],[14,'adminAnnouncements',20],[15,'adminUsers',21],[24,'dashProgramActivity',22],[25,'dashDashboard',23],[26,'dashStructure',24],[27,'dashResupply',25],[28,'dashInventory',26],[29,'dashTDPComments',27]];
        Ext.define('cf_gridmodel', { extend: 'Ext.data.Model', fields: _cf_gridColModel,idProperty : 'CFGRIDROWINDEX' });
        var _cf_gridDataModel = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', { model : 'cf_gridmodel', data: _cf_gridData,proxy: {  type: 'memory',reader : new Ext.data.reader.Array({id:_cf_gridColModel.length-1}, _cf_gridColModel)}});

        ColdFusion.Grid.init('FirstGrid','__CFGRID__assays__FirstGrid','assays',false,false,true,false,'MNU_MENU_ID',_cf_gridColModel,_cf_gridDataModel,500,310,true,'#cfgrid148239339981943 .x-grid-cell-FirstGrid_MNU_MENU_ID{color:#0B333C;} #cfgrid148239339981943 .x-grid-hd-FirstGrid_MNU_MENU_ID{color:#0B333C;} #cfgrid148239339981943 .x-grid-row-selected .x-grid-cell-FirstGrid_MNU_MENU_ID{background-color:#7FCDFE !important;} #cfgrid148239339981943 .x-grid-cell-FirstGrid_MNU_MENU{color:#0B333C;} #cfgrid148239339981943 .x-grid-hd-FirstGrid_MNU_MENU{color:#0B333C;} #cfgrid148239339981943 .x-grid-row-selected .x-grid-cell-FirstGrid_MNU_MENU{background-color:#7FCDFE !important;} #cfgrid148239339981943 .x-grid-cell-FirstGrid_CFGRIDROWINDEX{color:#0B333C;} #cfgrid148239339981943 .x-grid-hd-FirstGrid_CFGRIDROWINDEX{color:#0B333C;} #cfgrid148239339981943 .x-grid-row-selected .x-grid-cell-FirstGrid_CFGRIDROWINDEX{background-color:#7FCDFE !important;} #cfgrid148239339981943 .x-grid-row .x-grid-cell-FirstGrid_MNU_MENU_ID{background-color:null} #cfgrid148239339981943 .x-grid-row-alt .x-grid-cell-FirstGrid_MNU_MENU_ID{background-color:null} #cfgrid148239339981943 .x-grid-row .x-grid-cell-FirstGrid_MNU_MENU{background-color:null} #cfgrid148239339981943 .x-grid-row-alt .x-grid-cell-FirstGrid_MNU_MENU{background-color:null} #cfgrid148239339981943 .x-grid-row .x-grid-cell-FirstGrid_CFGRIDROWINDEX{background-color:null} #cfgrid148239339981943 .x-grid-row-alt .x-grid-cell-FirstGrid_CFGRIDROWINDEX{background-color:null} ',10,true,true,null,false,null,'test',null,null,{'appendKey':true,colInfo:[null,null,null]},null,null,null,null);
        Ext.form.ComboBox.prototype.triggerAction = 'all';
    };ColdFusion.Event.registerOnLoad(_cf_GRIDTAG_initAjaxGrid_148239339981944);
/* ]]> */</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    _CF_checkassays = function(_CF_this)
    {
        //reset on submit
        _CF_error_exists = false;
        _CF_error_messages = new Array();
        _CF_error_fields = new Object();
        _CF_FirstErrorField = null;


        //display error messages and return success
        if( _CF_error_exists )
        {
            if( _CF_error_messages.length > 0 )
            {
                // show alert() message
                _CF_onErrorAlert(_CF_error_messages);
                // set focus to first form error, if the field supports js focus().
                if( _CF_this[_CF_FirstErrorField].type == "text" )
                { _CF_this[_CF_FirstErrorField].focus(); }

            }
            return false;
        }else {
            return true;
        }
    }
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>

    0<br>
    1<br>
    2<br>
    2<br>
    3<br>
    3<br>
    4<br>
    5<br>
    5<br>
    6<br>
    7<br>
    8<br>
    9<br>
    <!-- Again, lines deleted that push the cfgrid below the bottom of the screen -->
    <form name="assays" id="assays" action="&#x2f;index.cfm" method="post" onsubmit="return _CF_checkassays(this)">
<div  id="cfgrid148239339981943" style="border: 1px solid #cccccc; overflow: hidden;height:310px;">

 </div> <div><input type="hidden" name="__CFGRID__assays__FirstGrid" value="" /></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look for a call to the JavaScript focus() function.

Comment: That, or look for an anchor tag near the grid. (`<a name="..." />`). Are there any javascripts specified in `OnXXX` attributes of the tag, like `onLoad`?

Comment: This is the sort of thing one needs to contend with if one uses ColdFusion UI wizards. Just don't use them. They're rubbish, and they are not of production-ready quality. Reading: https://github.com/cfjedimaster/ColdFusion-UI-the-Right-Way

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I'm coming into a project that is starting and this bug landed on my plate.  I'd look for <a>'s and there aren't any in the code that's rendered.  The only focus() call happens on an error in the grid and there aren't any errors.  There is no onload on the body tag.

Comment: I know you found a solution, but ... *RE: There is no onload on the body tag* Because it is using the `onLoad` event of the underlying library ExtJS (different than body onLoad). *RE: I haven't tried jQuery's .ready() yet* CF's grid uses a different library. Do not mix events from different libraries. They are not guaranteed to play well with each other. (Side note - though this one was easily solved, you will definitely run into more limitations and quirks if you spend any time working with `cfgrid`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions, @cfqueryparam.  But I found that the solution is to add the attribute `selectOnLoad="false"` to the `cfgrid` tag.  Its default value in CF11 is "true".  I'm not sure about CF10, but in CF9 is seems to default to "false".

Answer (score 1):

In the future, please provide direct code so that users here can work with exactly what you're working with. Using CF9, I couldn't replicate the behavior but like you said, you're using CF11.

Is this code you wrote, or code you inherited, or code you copied from somewhere (like a tutorial)? Are you sure it's CF-generated javascript causing the havoc and not a javascript designed to focus the grid?

If it's something you can't trace, and someone else doesn't have a better solution, this may work. It's currently set to 3000 (3 seconds), but a lower time should work better (and be less annoying to your users.

I would place it after your cfgrid.

```
<script>
  setTimeout(function(){ window.scrollTo(0,0); }, 3000);
</script>
```

---

You might also find a solution with this javascript.

```
var scrolled = 0;
window.onscroll = function() {
    if (!(scrolled)) {
        scrolled = 1;
        setTimeout(function(){ window.scrollTo(0,0); }, 300);
    }
};
```

But I'd place it only in your cfgrid's page, not across your site. Good way to annoy people otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. If I put this is a function that is called onLoad it works, but the page jumps down and then back up.  2000 and 1000 doesn't have an effect: The page remains at the bottom.

Comment: Since you didn't see in CF9, I'm thinking its a bug in CF11.

Comment: @user1286322 You might try adding it to the onLoad of CFGrid. Unfortunately the "rubberbanding" is a gross side effect `<cfgrid ... onLoad="setTimeout(function(){ window.scrollTo(0,0); }, 3000);" ...>` You might get away with shorter times in that fashion.

Comment: @user1286322 Additionally updated my answer with an alternate method that basically nixes the first attempt to scroll, but doesn't really affect the user's first scroll unless they grab. I feel like it's the better solution if it works.

Comment: *unless they grab, and release in under a third of a second, on their first scroll.